# Статистика Хи-квадрат

Tags: python, python-3.x

Применяю Хи-квадрат критерий, проверяю гипотезу о выборке из биномиального распределения с параметрами [21, 0.9].

```
from statsmodels.stats import gof
from scipy import stats


P0_VALUE = 0.05
xs = [19, 20, 20, 19, 20, 20, 19, 20, 20, 19, 18, 19, 21, 20, 19, 
19, 19, 21, 20, 19, 19, 20, 18, 20, 20, 16, 20, 17, 19, 19, 20, 19, 
20, 19, 20, 20, 21, 20, 21, 21, 19, 19, 20, 18, 20, 20, 21, 17, 18, 19]


res_chi_test = gof.gof_chisquare_discrete(stats.distributions.binom,
                                          arg=[21, 0.9], rvs=xs,
                                          alpha=P0_VALUE, msg="Binomial ")
print(res_chi_test)
```

Результат:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide terms = (f_obs_float - f_exp)**2 / f_exp
(nan, nan, False, 'chisquare - test for Binomial at arg = [21, 0.9] with pval = nan')
```

Т.е., видимо, где-то внутри происходит деление на "ноль" [скорее всего, из-за неоптимального выделения интервалов].
Вспоминаю, что `Bin[n, p]` эквивалентно `n - Bin[n, 1-p]`, изменяю выборку, меняю параметр 0.9 на 0.1, запускаю:

```
xs = [2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 
1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2]


res_chi_test = gof.gof_chisquare_discrete(stats.distributions.binom,
                                          arg=[21, 0.1], rvs=xs,
                                          alpha=P0_VALUE, msg="Binomial ")
print(res_chi_test)
```

Чудо(?)

```
(11.082247965399947, 0.0858674790344855, True, 'chisquare - test for Binomial at arg = [21, 0.1] with pval = 0.0858674790344855')
```

1. Почему все же так происходит?
2. Как этого избежать [не считая вариант самостоятельной реализации]?

Comment: Ну, так внимательно читая документацию https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.gof.gof_chisquare_discrete.html обнаруживаем вполне честное предупреждение: ".... still needs to be checked for standalone usage, insufficient input checking may not run yet (after copy/paste)"

Comment: @passant да, действительно...
А не знаете случайно про рабочие аналоги?

Comment: Вопрос не в аналогах. Что за параметры вы передаете arg= ?? Что-то мне подсказывает, что там должны быть значения (n,p) . А у вас что?

Comment: @passant Все так и есть, передаю [n ,p]: в самом начале вопроса писал, биномиальное распределение с параметрами [21, 0.9]
n=21, p=0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, спустя некоторое время я нашел разгадку.

Объект `stats.distributions.binom` по умолчанию определяет максимальное значение, принимаемое моделируемой СВ, как `inf`. При этом внутри `gof_chisquare_discrete()` максимальное значение определяется именно у передаваемого объекта [который в моем случае обладал значениями параметров по умолчанию], а сами параметры распределения при этом не учитываются. Из-за этого возникает лишний интервал `[n;inf)` с вероятностью попадания `0`. Потому в слагаемом, соответствующем этому интервалу, и возникает деление на 0.

Решение проблемы - передавать объект с конкретным набором параметров распределения, а в качестве `args` - `[]`:

```
res_chi_test = gof.gof_chisquare_discrete(stats.distributions.binom(21,0.9),
                                          arg=[], rvs=xs,
                                          alpha=P0_VALUE, msg="Binomial ")
```

Результат:

```
(11.077689191629469, 0.04986120886306524, False, 'chisquare - test for Binomial at arg = [] with pval = 0.04986120886306524')
```

Answer (score 1):

Хотите именно ХИ-2 тест -  придется строить вручную.

Можно задействовать тест Колмогорова-Смирнова:

```
stats.kstest(xs, "binom", (21, 0.9))
```

Его результат неутешителен:

```
KstestResult(statistic=0.4952700362282919, pvalue=7.51602278864889e-12)
```

т.е. считать ваши данные распределенными по биноминальному закону не приходится.
Впрочем, это и неудивительно, с оглядкой на их гистограмму.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Увы, в исходном задании речь идет конкретно о Хи-квадрат 
А по поводу гистограммы - честно говоря, не совсем понял, в чем проблема. С учетом размера выборки, выглядит она достаточно неплохо